# React .net core Web : Post Form data from react component to MVC controller

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've tried looking at other answers but its not clear to me. I am using visual studio 2022 template "react js .net core web  " template . I have a 'ProductController' in which i want to have some action method which receives form data  sent by  ajax or fetch api from react component and insert in database. please provive me some code if possible. so far i was trying this:
in prodcutController:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxMethod(string name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
```

in crud.js

```
 import { type } from "jquery";
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
 import $ from 'jquery'; 
    
 
function Crud(){

return (
    <>
        <form>
            <input type='text' name='product' placeholder = 'product' /> 
            <input type='text' name='price' placeholder='Price' />
            <button id="submit">Post</button>
        </form>
        
    </>
    )
{
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/product/AjaxMethod',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { name: 'replaceWithformDataJsn' },
                success: function (data) { alert('yes') },
                error: function () { alert('error') }


            })
        })
    })


}


}
export default Crud
```

Comment: that link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({ name: "", price: "" });
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetch('/api/product/AjaxMethod', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(product)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        alert('Product added successfully');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Error adding product');
    });
};
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type='text' name='product' placeholder='Product' onChange={event => setProduct({ ...product, name: event.target.value })} /> 
        <input type='text' name='price' placeholder='Price' onChange={event => setProduct({ ...product, price: event.target.value })} />
        <button type="submit">Post</button>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: thanks.can you please also define what goes in action method inside controller?